# What is the property of the exponential of second derivative $\exp[d^2/dx^2]$?

Tags: operator-theory, exponential-function

We know that the exponential derivative $e^{d/dx}$ has a shift property
$$
e^{d/dx}f(x)=f(x+1)
$$
And it can be proved using Taylor expansion.

I wonder whether $e^{d^2/dx^2}$ has a similar property. I can't prove it using Taylor expansion.

Comment: In other words: Evaluate $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(2k)}(x)}{k!}$$where $f^{(2k)}$ denotes the derivative of order $2k$.  Assume as much regularity for the function $f$ as necessary.

Comment: It must be said that the operator you mention at first ($\exp(d/dx)$) makes sense for a restricted set of functions : see here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2816127/305862

Comment: See as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1300606/305862).

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.

If we write
$$
F(x,t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(2k)}(x)\, t^k}{k!},\qquad x \in \mathbb R, t \ge 0,
\tag1$$
then the problem asks about $F(x,1)$.
Now $(1)$ satisfies the one-dimensional heat equation
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} F = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}F
$$
with initial condition
$$
F(x,0) = f(x) .
$$

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions) for the solution as a "convolution" with the "Green's function" like this:
$$
F(x,t) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}\right)\,f(y)\; dy .
$$

---

An interesting aside on this.  The heat equation does not obey Einstein's theory of relativity.  The value $F(x,t)$ depends on **all** of the function $f(x)$, not limited to $f(y)$ for locations $y$ near $x$; in particular, $F(x,1)$ encodes information about $f$ that cannot reach the location $x$ traveling below the speed of light.

Comment: [+1] Very interesting.

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel).